# access widget by Tk widget/window path name

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, tk-toolkit

I am using `validatecommand` to observe and validate the input of an entry widget 'dynamically'.

The standard usage of `validatecommand` prevents invalid characters from being entered to the observed entry widget. This is not the behaviour I like to have, so I used `validatecommand` to pass the string of the entry widget to another function and `return True` in any case. `floatstr_to_float` validates the string using a regular expression called `preg`.

If the regex matches the input is valid, everything is OK and therefore `print('approved')` is executed. However, if the user entered invalid input, the regex does not match, `print('not approved')` is executed and the appropriate entry widget should be filled red (change of color not implemented properly yet).

What I have done so far is changing the background of the very first entry widget using `<widget>.config(bg=<background>)` to check wheather I am able to access every widget by indexing a list of all created entry widgets.

`validatecommand` can pass several [arguments](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html) to the executed function (such as imput/text string and widget/window pathname). So getting a reference to the invalid widget in general is not a problem. However, the pathname passed by `validatecommand` does not seem to be python-accessable. How can I get a reference (e.g. unique variable name) from this pathname to change the background by executing `<widget>.config(bg=<background>)` on the widget containing (in)valid input?

-- MWE --

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: <utf-8> -*-

# code adapted from:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/python-tkinter-interactively-validating-entry-widget-content

import tkinter as tk
import re

class MyApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.parameternames = [
            ('a', 'U'), ('b', 'U'), ('c', 'U'), ('d', 'U'), ('e', 'U'),
            ('f', 'U'), ('g', 'U'), ('h', 'U'), ('i', 'U'), ('j', 'U'),
            ('k', 'U'), ('l', 'U'), ('m', 'U'), ('n', 'U'), ('o', 'U'),
            ('p', 'U'), ('q', 'U'), ('r', 'U'), ('s', 'U'), ('t', 'U')]
        self.vcmd = (self.root.register(self.OnValidate), '%P', '%W')
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.entries = []
        for i in enumerate(self.parameternames):
            entry = tk.Entry(self.root, validate="all", validatecommand=self.vcmd)
            self.default_bg = entry.cget("bg")
            entry.pack()
            self.entries.append(entry)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def OnValidate(self, P, W):
        # %P = value of the entry if the edit is allowed
        # %W = the tk name of the widget (pathname)
        print("OnValidate:")
        print("P='%s'" % P )
        print("W='%s'" % W )
        self.floatstr_to_float(P, W)
        # return True to display inserted character, validation is done by a re in 'floatstr_to_float()'
        return True

    def floatstr_to_float(self, fs, W):
        preg = re.compile('^\s*(?P<int>\d*)\s*[\.,]?\s*(?P<dec>\d*)\s*$')
        m = preg.match(fs)
        if m:
            print('approved')
            intprt=m.group('int')
            frcprt=m.group('dec')
            f = 0. if (intprt == '' and frcprt == '') else float('%s.%s' %(intprt, frcprt)) # not needed yet
            # currently:    just changing the color of the first entry widget (proof of concept)
            # aim:          pass unique name of edited entry widget to self.change_bg() for changing bg of
            #               appropriate entry widget
            self.change_bg(self.entries[0], 1)
        else:
            print('not approved')
            # see comment in if-statement above
            self.change_bg(self.entries[0], 0)

    def change_bg(self, name, approved):
        if approved == 1:
            name.config(bg=self.default_bg)
        else:
            name.config(bg='#d9534f')

app=MyApp()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `nametowidget` method of `Tk`. This finds the widget based on its name. So use:

```
self.change_bg(self.root.nametowidget(W), 1)
```